# How do get all the data from a single table in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to simply get all the data from a mysql table using the following code:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'table');
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$user_array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) 
        {
        $user_array[]=$row;
        }
    echo "<br />";
    echo "print r of user_array: <br />";
    print_r($user_array);
```

i'm getting nothing. I looked at this tutorial (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp), among others, but all they do is confuse me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The W3Schools tutorials are generally considered to be of low quality, and sometimes encourage poor practices. I recommend sticking to the examples in the [official MySQLi documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this

```
mysql_fetch_array($r)
```

to

```
mysqli_fetch_array($r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have connected via the procedural MySQLi API (`mysqli_connect()`), but you are attempting to use the old `mysql_fetch_array()` from the old `mysql_*()` API. They aren't compatible.

You need to fetch via `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead. [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) is recommended unless you really need numeric keys in addition to column names in the output `$row`:

```
// Check for errors.
if ($r) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $user_array[] = $row;
  }
}
else echo mysqli_error($dbc);
```

What you're working with now is a simple query with no parameters, just a `SELECT *` without a `WHERE` clause.  For the future, when you start adding `WHERE` conditions, you'll want to start reading about prepared statements and [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).